# JavaScript send custom headers using a script tag only

Tags: javascript, http, header, http-headers, tags

I want to make a client-side application that loads JavaScript files using only script-tags, (and not fetch, due to cross-origin concerns), but I was wondering if its possible to somehow set the custom request headers in the script tag, such that I can receive only part of a file (the equivalent to sending the range: `bytes 10-40` header), or other custom headers the server may request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. A script tag will create a regular HTTP GET request without any means to control the headers.

Comment: oh brutal, ok then. do you know if theres some other way to read / include part of a javascript file from a cross-origin site?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? Never stumbled upon such a case. Maybe save the partial js file as a new file and refer to that one on the client.

Comment: basically I have a large JS file that acts as a database for a large amount of data, it is filled with a list of function calls, each call taking up about 5-60 KB of data, one following the other. I have another file, index.js, which keeps track of the byte offset of each function call, so the idea is that when the user clicks on a certain button that is asociated with a certain number value, the data from index.js checks what byte-offset the function call necessary for that button press is associated with, and loads only part of that file. It would be massively impractical to split it up

Comment: because I have a series of these large "javascript database files", and each one could be anywhere from 500kb - 4mb, and if I split it up each one could be split up into 10-200 separate files, which would result in 20,000 files total to upload to my server (for later offline download use), as opposed to just 1,500 if I do it this way, and it takes a longer time to upload more files with less space than less files with more space

Comment: Maybe post a new question. Hope you've found my answer useful

Comment: @bluejayke out of curiosity: why on earth are you using javascript files for storing data?

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj how else am I supposed to load the data from either offline with no server, or from a server that doesnt have CORs enabled?

Comment: @bluejayke it seems very fragile, what happens to all your byte offsets when you need to modify the data in some file? How would you maintain something like that? A sane approach to this would be to have a web server send the data to the client. The client can then persist the data on the client for offline use by using e.g IndexedDB https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API. I'm not sure how this js file approach would help with offline usage, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj but this is meant to be a completely offline solution, that should work for months at a time, just being downlaoded on a computer. if I'm understanding this correct, you're saying that I should have the client first go to a website, then that webste (/server) would download all of the content necessary (20,000+ files), and then they would be able to read all of the content based on the cache on their computer? what if they clear their cache?